# IF Statement for two columns

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I am trying to enter a value in a cell based on the results in 2 different cells. if cell 1 is blank then refer to cell 2, based on what's in cell 2 return X value.

If cell 1 is NOT blank, based on what's in cell 1 return X value.

here is what I have so far, so far everything that looks in cell 1 returns a FALSE.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(E8),IF(D8="401K Employer Match","Match",IF(D8="401K Percentage","4K",IF(D8="ROTH 401K %","4R",IF(D8="Life Employee","LIE",IF(D8="Life Spouse","LIS",IF(D8="Life Child(ren)","LIC",IF(D8="Life Employer","LE",IF(D8="Life Employer X 2","LE2",IF(D8="Short Term Disabilty Base Pay","STDB",IF(D8="Short Term Disability Gross Wages","STDG",IF(D8="Short Term Disability Over 60K","STDB",IF(D8="Long Term Disability Base Salary","LTDB",IF(D8="Long Term Disability Gross Wages","LTDG",IF(D8="Long Term Disability Over 60K","D")))))))))))))),If(E8="Reliance Dental","DE"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are trying to put 3+ nested ifs, it is a good idea to use a LookUp Table. Like this:

[image]

Then you simply look for the value in column `A` and return the value in Column `B`. And you save yourself all the problems that a long Excel formula causes.

This is how a formula looks like:

```
"=INDEX(A2:B4,MATCH(D2,A2:A4,0),2)"
```

Just put it somewhere and make sure that you change `D2` correspondingly:

[image]

Comment: That's better than how I was going to try to explain it.

Comment: By the way the reason you were getting a "FALSE" is because this IF statement doesn't have a *`value if false`* : If(E8="Reliance Dental","DE"), instead of a "no match" option.  But still, you want a table like suggested here.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider using IFS() statements. 
=IFS(*condition*, then do XYZ, *different condition*, then do ABC, etc.)